# why can't karma see the js files ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, karma-runner

trying to get karma up and running, getting the following error messages, karma doesn't seem to see the js files, not sure how to correct that and is subsequently not seeing the angular module. i've looked at the docs and the karma docs as well but not seeing a solution.

thoughts?

i'm basing this setup off of honeybadger.io 
https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails

```
^C[jd@mbp ~/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch (master *)]$ karma start spec/javascripts/lunch.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/angular.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/angular-mocks.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/angular-route.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/angular/*" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/app.js.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/controllers.js.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/app/assets/javascripts/services.js.coffee" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.9.1)]: Connected on socket LuVlKBCaXZHpAuDSxZbt
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.9.1) Lunch controller encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    ReferenceError: module is not defined
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/lunch_controller_spec.js.js:2:14)
        at /Users/jd/Dropbox/angular_projects/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/lunch_controller_spec.js.js:1:1
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.9.1): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (3.955 secs / 0.779 secs)
```

my app.js.coffee

```
Lunch = angular.module('Lunch', ['ngRoute','Lunch.controllers', 'Lunch.services'])

Lunch.config([ '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "/ngviews/lunch.html", controller: "LunchCtrl" } )
])
```

my spec file looks like

```
describe "Lunch controller", ->
  beforeEach module("Lunch")

  describe "LunchCtrl", ->
    it "should set images to a populated array", inject(($controller) ->
      scope = {}
      ctrl = $controller("LunchCtrl",
        $scope: scope
      )
      expect(scope.luncher.length).toBe 4
    )
```

and my spec/javascripts/lunch.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    autoWatch: true,
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.coffee': 'coffee'
    },
    files: [
    'app/assets/javascripts/angular.js',
    'app/assets/javascripts/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/assets/javascripts/angular-route.js',
    'app/assets/javascripts/angular/*',
    'app/assets/javascripts/app.js.coffee',
    'app/assets/javascripts/controllers.js.coffee',
    'app/assets/javascripts/services.js.coffee',
    'spec/javascripts/*_spec.js.coffee'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: in your lunch.conf.js you have a lot of *.js files that will not be found by karma. I think the path to these files is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up copying a conf file that I found on the internet, that seems to be working though there is def some kind of conflict with the js from zurb foundation.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    autoWatch: true,
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.coffee': 'coffee'
    },
    files: [
      'http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js',
      'spec/javascripts/lunch_controller_spec.js.coffee',
      {
        pattern: 'app/assets/javascripts/*.{js,coffee}',
        watched: true,
        included: false,
        served: false
      }
    ]
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Karma can't find the files because of the default coffee preprocessor naming convention.

The preprocessor expect to find .coffee-files (i.e. app.coffee) and provides .js-files after processing (app.js). Your files are named .js.coffee (Looks like you're doing rails), so they are provided at file.js.js.
If you give it a try and look for 'localhost:9876/base/app/assets/javascripts/angular.js.js' you will find the file there.

Solution:
Following the docs (https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coffee-preprocessor) you can add this to your karma.conf.js:

```
coffeePreprocessor: {
    // options passed to the coffee compiler
    options: {
        bare: false,
        sourceMap: true
    },
    // transforming the filenames
    transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.js.coffee$/, '.js');
    }
},
```

and find the files at the expected location (and so karma will, too):
localhost:9876/base/app/assets/javascripts/angular.js